# Why am I hitting the datastore read operation quota?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gae-quotas

I was in a place without Internet access for 3 weeks and just came back to find out that one of my apps since January 18 started to reach a quota limit (Datastore Read Operations) after around the 18 hours.
I don't see any increase in traffic from either users or crawlers.
This is the error in the logs:
"The API call datastore_v3.RunQuery() required more quota than is available."

It seems very strange since this application has been running for some years and I'm memcaching most the datastore requests.

Please help - This is affecting my bottom line!
Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to help you without more knowledge about your application. try runnning appstats, and see which requests are taking the most read operations. Also, traffic may not be the only source of more read operations. If your entity gets bigger, or other things about your objects ore schema change, it could be affecting the number of reads required.

Comment: I had appstats enabled for sometime, but couldn't make much sense of it. The entities haven't got bigger for quite some time and they take very little room (1MB) and 37MB with the indexes. 
Nothing changed in my app because I'm the only one with access to it.
Do you know of any changes in GAE last week?

Comment: I have several other apps and none of them are having this problem. However, this is the only one where my "main" entities are defined like this:
class EntityName(search.SearchableModel):
  @classmethod
  def SearchableProperties(cls):
    return [['field1', 'field2', 'field3']]

Could that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a subset of pages in the site that had got a sudden interest from several crawlers and some of the requests that those pages made to the Datastore were not being memcached, so that was it...problem solved.
Thanks.